# Is the answer to this truth-statement evaluation wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, logic

I have been working through an analysis course and the solutions to some of the exercies presented appear to make no sense.
The exercise reads as follows.

> Determine which of the following are true:
>
> 1. $(\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} )(\exists y \in \mathbb{Z})(\frac{x}{y}>0) $

I view the evaluation of such truth statemets a bit like a game where a challenger(usually the statement that appears after the $\forall$ quantifier) picks numbers $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and I am trying to find(usually whatever appears after the $\exists$ quantifier) a suitable number $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ that satisfies the condition for any possible $x$ the challenger could pick.

My answer is as follows.

> The statement is false. This is because for $x = 0$ there exists no possible $y$ which satisfies $\frac{x}{y}>0$. At best, we could have $\frac{x}{y} = 0$ which is NOT strictly larger than $0$.

Now, onto main issue. The source I am using appears to disagree entirely with my argument. Their answers are as follows. Please note that I am quoting the solutions verbatim.

> The first statement is true since one can take y = x.

I disagree with this answer, because one can easily pick $ x = 0 $ and run into all sorts of trouble.

Have I missed something? Thank you in advance for any help you may provide.

Comment: You are right, you cannot choose $y=0$. – Which source claims that $\frac 0 0 > 0$ makes any sense?

Comment: You are correct, and that this is in an analysis course is worrying.

Comment: @MartinR
I do not wish to name and shame but it's an old course(2001-2002) from one of the top universities in the UK that has been made available online and has been kept online since.

There are other typographical errors that I had spotted throughout the work, but nothing so far had made me question the veracity of the statements and proofs presented throughout, especially considering the reputation of the institution that it came out of.

Comment: Is it a publicly available course? In that case you could post the link, perhaps we find  something which explains it. – Without more information, the only answer to your question is “yes, you are right, and they are wong” :)

Comment: @MartinR 

The course is [this one here](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~john/analysis/index.html) and I was looking at "Excercises 1, Question 3".

Comment: @Lyric: Thanks for the link. You quoted the question and their solution correctly. The answer is still “Yes, you are right, and they are wong.”

Comment: I am closing this question, as Math SE is not really a good place for documenting errata.  Nearly every textbook, published article, or collection of lecture notes contains typographical and other errors.  This website is not really an appropriate place for archiving such errors.